# show that the Power series solve the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

> $$f(t)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{ (-1)^k\,(t/2)^{2k}}{(k!)^2}$$ 
>   show  $t\, f''(t)+f'(t)+t\, f(t)=0$

By differentiating it, I got

$$f'(t)= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac {(-1)^k\,(2k)(t)^{2k-1}}{(k!)^2 \,2^{2k}}$$

and $$f''(t)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k(2k)(2k-1)(t)^{2k-2}}{(k!)^2 \, 2^{2k}}$$

when I plug these into the equation I then have LHS of the equation

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2k)^2+t^2}{(k!)^2 \, 2 ^{2k}}$$

Where did I make my mistake? I couldn't end up with the $LHS=0$.

Comment: Compare the coefficients in front of each power of $t$ separately (you will have to shift at least one of the series).

Comment: so my f'(t) should be from 1 instead of 0 and f''(t) should be from 2 right?

Comment: Or you can shift only in the $tf(t)$.